# Unable to load custom SVG in mat-icon

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to load a custom SVG in the `MatIconRegistry` with the following code in my component

```
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder,
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace(
      'capp',
      'reassign',
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../../../../assets/images/reassign.svg')
    );
    this.form = fb.group({
      query: ''
    });
  }
```

But when I use this in the browser with `<mat-icon svgIcon="capp:reassign"></mat-icon>`

I get the following error in the console

```
Error retrieving icon: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

I have tried various relative paths for the SVG which is located in an images folder under assets, I have tried `./`, `/`, and making it relative to the route which is `../../`

The only way I have been able to get it to work is by specifying the full URL but this would be different when deployed and I understood the path to the SVG should be relative

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I have been able to get it to work is by specifying the full URL but this would be different when deployed

You've already solved the problem here: it expects an absolute URL rather than a relative one.

To solve the "different when deployed" issue you could consider using `window.location.origin`, which will work for any environment provided the app's base url is `/`.

```
matIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace(
  'capp',
  'reassign',
  domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.location.origin + '/assets/images/reassign.svg')
);
```